# Best practice for adding metadata in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, metadata

I want to use the metadata tags in our sharepoint portal application. This should not be hard coded and need to be based on pages. The user should be able to search based on metadata tags. How can we do this without hardcoding ? Please suggest a best way to do this.

EDIT

I want to tag the metadata keywords in the pages, so that the user will be able to search based on that. I think the  can be used for that purpose, but I don't want to hard code the keywords. These keywords may be configurable and hence need to store outside the page. I hope this will give an idea about what I'm trying to achieve. (I have heard about managed metadata, but don't know much about that. Does that serve my purpose ?)

Comment: Your requirements are not very clear to me. Could you elaborate and perhaps give an example of what you are expecting?

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check and let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enterprise Metadata](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/configure-enterprise-metadata-and-keyword-settings-for-a-list-or-library-HA101665479.aspx) for tagging pages

> Enterprise keywords are shared with other users and applications to
>   allow for ease of search and filtering, as well as metadata
>   consistensy and reuse

Enterprise keywords are organized into a single, non-hierarchical term set within the Term Store Management Tool called the Keywords set. Because users can typically add any word or phrase to an item as a keyword, enterprise keywords can be used for folksonomy-style tagging.

Comment: How does it work? I'm developing the application and how should I integrate the same in pages ? Content Type Hub is a part of it ?

Comment: How to integrate is described in the link I added in the answer. If you want to know more about the contentype hub please look at this post http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/understanding-content-type-hub-cth-in-sharepoint-2013